# Connect JDBC in maven web project on eclipse

Tags: sql-server, maven, web, jdbc

I'm trying to connect my MAVEN WEB PROJECT to MSSQLServer using jdbc connection string,
my project is already connected to a PostgreSQL data source by the web server.
:

**Code:**

```
Connection con;
try{DriverManager.registerDriver(new SQLServerDriver());}
catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace()}
String url="jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER\\INSTANCE:1433;DatabaseName=myDatabase";
String userName = "user";
String userPass = "123456";
try{con = DriverManager.getConnection(url ,userName , userPass);}
catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace()}
```

---

**Exception:**

> The TCP/IP connection the the host SERVER, port 1433 has failed. >Error: "connect timed out. verify the connection properties. Make sure that an >instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections >at the port.
>
> The Network services for the SQL server are runing on the server and the port is set to 1433, and it is added to the firewall allowed ports

I've tried the same code in a regular java project and it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you using variables to create the jdbc url string? In order to help you, make a demo of your code, for instance, with a simple "select" and share us it.

Comment: `Connection con;
try{DriverManager.registerDriver(new SQLServerDriver());}
catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace()}
String url="jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER\\INSTANCE:1433;DatabaseName=myDatabase";
String userName = "user";
String userPass = "123456";
try{con = DriverManager.getConnection(url ,userName , userPass);}
catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace()}` This method return the Connection variable

Comment: Please **edit** your question, do not add code or other relevant information in the comments, but add them to your question. Also, have you actually followed the instructions of the error message? That is: _"Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. The Network services for the SQL server are running on the server and the port is set to 1433, and it is added to the firewall allowed ports"_. Also note that instance names are ignored if you specify an explicit port number.